# Moving all the contents of one vector into a new vector

Tags: rust, vector, memory-management

To make a new vector with the content of an old vector (which I want to be emptied) I'm going to use:

```
foo.bar = my_vector.drain(0..).collect();
```

Is this idiomatic Rust?

Is the drain() optimised away, and the original vector's memory just given to the new vector?

Or is every element copied one-by-one into a fresh heap allocation?

Comment: I'd imagine it's preferable to use `foo.bar.clear(); foo.bar.extend(my_vector.drain(0..)))` to avoid potentially creating an additional allocation.

Comment: [Always run Clippy on your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=27fe16d53abac0a3955135aa4db39555). Also, better to use the open range, `..`.

Comment: Note that it's impossible for the standard library to optimize `v.drain(..).collect()` to just move the pointer. A vector [guarantees](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees) that it will only shrink its storage if you explicitly do so, so the old vector must retain all of its memory.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks, I hadn't heard of Clippy before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do

```
foo.bar = std::mem::take(&mut my_vector);
```

This is a more general solution.

[`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) mutates its parameter in order to *steal* its content and leave it in its default state.
The stolen content is used to create a new value of the same type.

The actual *stealing* operation is a simple byte swap of the structure itself (a few pointers/integers for a `Vec`, a `String`, any other container...).
The stored elements, which are probably heap-allocated, stay in place, thus this operation in the end is very cheap (copy then clear very few bytes, i.e. `sizeof` the structure).

Comment: [There is even a (warn-by-default!) Clippy lint for that!](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#/drain_collect)

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest way to move all the elements from one `Vec` to another is to `take` them:

```
foo.bar = std::mem::take(&mut my_vector);
```

This will give ownership of the allocation and all the elements to `foo.bar` and leave `my_vector` in a default state (empty with no allocated space).

You *could* use `.drain()` + `.collect()` to move elements while preserving `my_vector`'s allocation, but you can avoid the copying cost by instead using the above method and simply `.reserve()` the space back again afterwards.

---

In the off chance that `foo.bar` also has elements or space allocated, it might be better to `swap` them (exchanging their elements and allocation) and then clearing `my_vector` if you want it empty:

```
std::mem::swap(&mut foo.bar, &mut my_vector);
my_vector.clear();
```

This can avoid an allocation when putting elements in `my_vector` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the compiler sees that optimization, I'm not entirely sure it's valid either. You can see [on the compiler explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/PY4aeP3s7) that your code does emit allocation followed by a `memmove`:

```asm
//…
355:         mov     edi, 396
356:         mov     esi, 4
357:         call    qword ptr [rip + __rust_alloc@GOTPCREL]
//…
442:         call    qword ptr [rip + memmove@GOTPCREL]
//…
```

To `drain` a whole vector I'd use `drain(..)` the fewer explicit numbers the better, but even truer to your intent would probably be

```rust
foo.bar = std::mem::take(&mut my_vector);
```

or

```rust
let cap = my_vector.capacity();
foo.bar = std::mem::replace(&mut my_vector, Vec::with_capacity(cap));
```

Comment: It's not valid since `drain()` must preserve the capacity, and therefore you must allocate, and therefore also move.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a reallocation, use [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html), as @prog-fh already answered.

I just wanted to add examples on what effect this has on the generated machine code.

Here is what your code compiles to:

```rust
pub fn move_drain(my_vector: &mut Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>{
    my_vector.drain(0..).collect()
}
```

```
core::ptr::drop_in_place<alloc::vec::Vec<u8>>:
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB0_1
        mov     edx, 1
        jmp     qword ptr [rip + __rust_dealloc@GOTPCREL]
.LBB0_1:
        ret

core::ptr::drop_in_place<alloc::vec::drain::Drain<u8>>:
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        lea     rax, [rip + .Lanon.716d6a888caeb235278dc75f1465c66b.0]
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        mov     rbx, qword ptr [rdi + 32]
        cmp     rcx, qword ptr [rdi]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 8], rax
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .LBB1_4
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 16]
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rdi + 24]
        lea     r14, [rax + 16]
        mov     r15, qword ptr [rax + 16]
        cmp     rsi, r15
        je      .LBB1_3
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rax]
        add     rsi, rdi
        add     rdi, r15
        mov     rdx, rbx
        call    qword ptr [rip + memmove@GOTPCREL]
.LBB1_3:
        add     r15, rbx
        mov     qword ptr [r14], r15
.LBB1_4:
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        ret

alloc::raw_vec::finish_grow:
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdx
        mov     r14, rdi
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB2_6
        mov     r15, rsi
        cmp     qword ptr [rcx + 8], 0
        je      .LBB2_7
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rcx + 16]
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB2_7
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rcx]
        mov     rdx, r15
        mov     rcx, rbx
        call    qword ptr [rip + __rust_realloc@GOTPCREL]
        test    rax, rax
        jne     .LBB2_11
.LBB2_4:
        mov     qword ptr [r14 + 8], r15
        jmp     .LBB2_5
.LBB2_7:
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .LBB2_8
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + __rust_no_alloc_shim_is_unstable@GOTPCREL]
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rax]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        mov     rsi, r15
        call    qword ptr [rip + __rust_alloc@GOTPCREL]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB2_4
.LBB2_11:
        mov     qword ptr [r14 + 8], rax
        xor     eax, eax
        jmp     .LBB2_12
.LBB2_6:
        mov     qword ptr [r14 + 8], 0
.LBB2_5:
        mov     eax, 1
.LBB2_12:
        mov     qword ptr [r14 + 16], rbx
        mov     qword ptr [r14], rax
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        ret
.LBB2_8:
        mov     rax, r15
        test    rax, rax
        jne     .LBB2_11
        jmp     .LBB2_4

alloc::raw_vec::RawVec<T,A>::reserve::do_reserve_and_handle:
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 56
        add     rsi, rdx
        jb      .LBB3_10
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        lea     rcx, [rax + rax]
        cmp     rcx, rsi
        cmova   rsi, rcx
        cmp     rsi, 9
        mov     r14d, 8
        cmovae  r14, rsi
        mov     rsi, r14
        not     rsi
        shr     rsi, 63
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB3_2
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rbx]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rcx
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], 1
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rax
        jmp     .LBB3_4
.LBB3_2:
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], 0
.LBB3_4:
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 32]
        lea     rcx, [rsp + 8]
        mov     rdx, r14
        call    alloc::raw_vec::finish_grow
        cmp     qword ptr [rsp + 32], 0
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 40]
        je      .LBB3_5
        movabs  rax, -9223372036854775807
        cmp     rdi, rax
        jne     .LBB3_8
        add     rsp, 56
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        ret
.LBB3_5:
        mov     qword ptr [rbx], rdi
        mov     qword ptr [rbx + 8], r14
        add     rsp, 56
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        ret
.LBB3_8:
        test    rdi, rdi
        jne     .LBB3_9
.LBB3_10:
        call    qword ptr [rip + alloc::raw_vec::capacity_overflow@GOTPCREL]
        ud2
.LBB3_9:
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rsp + 48]
        call    qword ptr [rip + alloc::alloc::handle_alloc_error@GOTPCREL]
        ud2

example::move_drain:
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    r13
        push    r12
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 112
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsi]
        mov     r14, qword ptr [rsi + 16]
        mov     qword ptr [rsi + 16], 0
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 72], rax
        add     rax, r14
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 80], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 88], rsi
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 96], r14
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 104], 0
        test    r14, r14
        je      .LBB4_1
        setns   al
        js      .LBB4_5
        movzx   r15d, al
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + __rust_no_alloc_shim_is_unstable@GOTPCREL]
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rax]
        mov     rdi, r14
        mov     rsi, r15
        call    qword ptr [rip + __rust_alloc@GOTPCREL]
        test    rax, rax
        jne     .LBB4_2
        mov     rdi, r15
        mov     rsi, r14
        call    qword ptr [rip + alloc::alloc::handle_alloc_error@GOTPCREL]
        jmp     .LBB4_6
.LBB4_1:
        mov     eax, 1
.LBB4_2:
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], r14
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], 0
        vmovups ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsp + 72]
        vmovups ymmword ptr [rsp + 32], ymm0
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rsp + 104]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 64], rcx
        mov     r15, qword ptr [rsp + 32]
        mov     r12, qword ptr [rsp + 40]
        mov     rdx, r12
        sub     rdx, r15
        cmp     r14, rdx
        jae     .LBB4_3
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 8]
        xor     esi, esi
        vzeroupper
        call    alloc::raw_vec::RawVec<T,A>::reserve::do_reserve_and_handle
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rsp + 24]
        jmp     .LBB4_11
.LBB4_3:
        xor     ecx, ecx
.LBB4_11:
        mov     r13, qword ptr [rsp + 48]
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rsp + 56]
        mov     r14, qword ptr [rsp + 64]
        cmp     r15, r12
        je      .LBB4_14
.LBB4_12:
        movzx   edx, byte ptr [r15]
        inc     r15
        mov     byte ptr [rax + rcx], dl
        inc     rcx
        cmp     r15, r12
        jne     .LBB4_12
.LBB4_14:
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rcx
        test    r14, r14
        je      .LBB4_18
        mov     r15, qword ptr [r13 + 16]
        cmp     rsi, r15
        je      .LBB4_17
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [r13]
        add     rsi, rdi
        add     rdi, r15
        mov     rdx, r14
        vzeroupper
        call    qword ptr [rip + memmove@GOTPCREL]
.LBB4_17:
        add     r15, r14
        mov     qword ptr [r13 + 16], r15
.LBB4_18:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsp + 24]
        mov     qword ptr [rbx + 16], rax
        vmovups xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsp + 8]
        vmovups xmmword ptr [rbx], xmm0
        mov     rax, rbx
        add     rsp, 112
        pop     rbx
        pop     r12
        pop     r13
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        vzeroupper
        ret
.LBB4_5:
        call    qword ptr [rip + alloc::raw_vec::capacity_overflow@GOTPCREL]
.LBB4_6:
        ud2
        mov     rbx, rax
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 32]
        call    core::ptr::drop_in_place<alloc::vec::drain::Drain<u8>>
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rsp + 16]
        call    core::ptr::drop_in_place<alloc::vec::Vec<u8>>
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume@PLT
        ud2
        mov     rbx, rax
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 72]
        call    core::ptr::drop_in_place<alloc::vec::drain::Drain<u8>>
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume@PLT
        ud2

.Lanon.716d6a888caeb235278dc75f1465c66b.0:

DW.ref.rust_eh_personality:
        .quad   rust_eh_personality
```

In contrast, here with `std::mem::take`:

```rust
pub fn move_take(my_vector: &mut Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>{
    std::mem::take(my_vector)
}
```

```
example::move_take:
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rsi + 16]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 16], rcx
        vmovups xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi]
        vmovups xmmword ptr [rdi], xmm0
        mov     qword ptr [rsi], 1
        vxorps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        vmovups xmmword ptr [rsi + 8], xmm0
        ret
```